# Cannot remove file uucp

Tags: permissions, java

I was downloading Java tar files and meanwhile managed to install it via apt-get, now I cannot remove the unrelated file resting on my Desktop (jre1.8...). THe properties reveal owner uucp, and the permission field is grey.

Could someone help me kill it through the CL?

Thanks.

[THe file and the permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5yVX.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to remove the file as *superuser*.

So, open a terminal pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and move the working directory to Desktop position:

```
cd Desktop
```

Now you can run the following command that will delete selected file as *superuser* :

```
sudo rm -f <filename>
```

where parameter <filename> is the name (or the path) of file that you want delete.
The option **-f** tell to the command to ignore possible errors and force the deletion.

If you want to delete a directory you can use the following command that will delete the directory and all its content (**-r** means recursive, "go deep"):

```
sudo rm -rf <directory>
```

**Note**: unless you want to bypass all errors during deletion, don't use **-f** option. Be careful when you use the above command because, if you use it in the wrong way, you could delete important files and directories ignoring any errors that could arise. Those files cannot be recovered easily.
For example you **mustn't** use this command on your root directory.

---

If you want more information about `rm` command with this:

```
man rm
```

The above command will show you the reference manual of `rm` command.

I hope this could help you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I've tried yet the error pops-up:
"rm: cannot remove ‘jre1.8.0_77’: Is a directory"

Comment: Then you can use `sudo rm -rf <filename>` where -r option will delete files and directories recursively.

Comment: @Mookey Could you accept my answer? In this way you show to the community that this is a working and verified answer. Thanks.